# A low bandwidth mesh network for RC planes

Tags: communication, radio, wifi

I am looking for suggestions of a low bandwidth (<1 kbps) mesh network which can be implemented between RC model planes. It should be able to communicate over distances of 500m or more, preferably 1km+, and it should gracefully handle the loss of nodes in the network.

It should be legal worldwide to operate; at least Europe and the USA if that is not possible. And, it must be relatively cheap to implement.

This is for an RC plane game I am developing. Real world model aircraft in dogfights. Or racing each other. It will be part of Super OSD.

Comment: or flying in complex formations?

Comment: Yes, that could also be supported.

Comment: 1Km+ may be what your after, but in the UK it's illegal to fly more than 500m away or without a direct line of sight, see the DIY Drones site for more info -> http://bit.ly/as8ZBx

Comment: I'm not using UAV's, these will be piloted by people. If someone writes code for it which enables it to fly in a UAV config though it wouldn't be anything to do with me.

Comment: Sorry, it's all small unmanned aircraft including UAV's - I should have been more explicit, these regulations cover both RCs and drones.

Comment: I have never heard of that. But I will look it up. BTW, "unmanned" usually means no pilot, not just that the pilot doesn't fly with the aircraft, unless I'm missing something...?

Comment: To anyone who's interested, here's the proof of concept - the idea works: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_fjUtqqX0M

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the 900MHz band XBEE modules. They can get great range. They are relatively easy to operate and you can sleep them when not being used.

Comment: Do you know what the chip is in these? (I believe that the 2.4GHz ones use the Ember EM250)

Comment: Xbee-PRO sounds interesting. 1.6km range! However, that's only the US version; the EU version is only 10mW power... about 250m if it scales linearly.

Comment: It does not scale linearly, but It should have a table/graph to give you info about range at different powers. Joby, I am not sure which they use.

Comment: Sorry, I think Europe operates on 866MHz, not on 900MHz.

Comment: I'd stick with 2.4 GHz if you have justifiable cause to think international as that's a global ISM band versus the 8-900 bands.  XBee-PRO® DigiMesh™ 2.4 (Int'l): Line of sight range: 2500 ft (750 m)  http://www.digi.com/products/wireless/zigbee-mesh/xbee-digimesh-2-4.jsp#specs

Comment: Yeah, I realize international you want 2.4GHz, but the issue here is per country you can have a variance in allowed radiated power. I believe that Europe keeps it lower. Less power gets better range at 866/900.